# How to retrieve products that are in "waiting to arrive" mode

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have 3 tables (Orders, Order-Rows, Stock). They are related as follows:
ORDERS.ID = ORDER-ROWS.ORDER-ID (1 to many)
ORDER-ROWS.EAN = STOCK.EAN (many to many)
In an attempt to get rid of the many to many relationship, I added a column to Order-Rows.

```
Order_number = RELATED('orders'[order])
```

What I would like to figure out is how to get a list of all products that are **needed to fulfill an order**. This concerns all orders with the status 'backorder'.
That means I need to figure out **which products** are **not sent** yet, or are **not placed in backorder** yet. I hope my images of sample tables can make this complex question a bit easier to understand.

[image]

The table to come out eventually in PowerBi may also have a single row for every product needed per order. It doesn't specifically needs to have the quantity-column.

EDIT / UPDATE 01-29-2021, 18:09:
I made a mistake in my first sample-image; there is no product-column in the stock-table. To put that right I uploaded a second image showing the true situation.
**THIS IS THE RIGHT TABLE SITUATION**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved quite easily using a well crafted model.

First we need to create a Product table an then we can create the relationships between Product and both Order Rows and Stock tables, using the EAN colum.

We already have a relationship between Orders and OrdersRows on the OrderID column, we need to add a relationship between Orders and Stock using the Ordernumber column.

The model we want is this

[image: model]

For the sake of the example I created the Product table using this code, that takes just those that are present into the Stock table. The real Product table should contain all possible products appearing in Stock and OrderRows table.

*Note: this simple code doesn't work anymore after the removal of the Product column from the Stock table. See below for the new working (and longer) version*

```
Product = ALL( Stock[EAN], Stock[Product] )
```

We can now write a measure that checks if the order in the current selection is in Status "Backorder", then per each product in order counts how many are already sent o in backorder and finally computes the difference with the order quantity. If the difference is greater than 0 the measure returns a non-blank value to be shown in the table.

```
Quantity waiting for = 
IF(
    SELECTEDVALUE(Orders[Status]) = "Backorder",
    VAR SentOrBackorder = 
        CALCULATE(
            COUNTROWS( Stock ),
            Stock[Location] IN { "sent", "backorder" } 
        )
    VAR Missing = SUM(OrdersRows[Quantity]) - SentOrBackorder
    RETURN         
    IF (
        Missing > 0,
        Missing
    )
)
```

This measure can be used in a table together with `Orders[Order]`, `Orders[Date]`, `'Product'[Product]`

[image: table visual]

[image: table visual properties]

Of course, imrovements can be made, for instance:

1. Use Order name also for the relationship between Orders and
   OrdersRows.
2. Get rid of unused ID colums, that have a great impact over table
   size in memory, since they contain unique values and therefore
   requires big dictionaries to be built in Vertipaq engine.
3. Change the measure to implement correct aggregation, to compute totals.

Edit: since the specification changed with the removal of the Product column from the Stock table, the DAX code for the product calculated table changes to a more complex version, that handles product that are present in the Stock table but not in the OrdersRows. EAN is used as Product name when missing.

```
Product =
VAR OrderEAN =
    ALL ( OrdersRows[EAN] )
VAR StockEAN =
    ALL ( Stock[EAN] )
VAR StockOnlyEAN =
    EXCEPT (
        StockEAN,
        OrderEAN
    )
VAR OrderProduct =
    ALL (
        OrdersRows[EAN],
        OrdersRows[Product]
    )
VAR StockProduct =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            VALUES ( Stock[EAN] ),
            "Product", Stock[EAN]
        ),
        StockOnlyEAN
    )
VAR Result =
    UNION (
        OrderProduct,
        StockProduct
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

In a real scenario, the Product table should not be implemented in DAX but should be read directly from the data source.

Comment: this is the link to the github page with the saved example files https://github.com/SergioMurru/shared/tree/main/Ekfa%20How%20to%20retrieve%20products%20that%20are%20in%20waiting%20to%20arrive%20mode

Comment: WoW! Great work.
I have to apologize for a big mistake I made in my sample... I said there was a column 'product' in the STOCK-table, but there isn't... Is there any way to fix this dispite of my failure? I'm so sorry for the effort you put in.
I'll put in a new picture with the right situation ;-(

Comment: No big deal. I changed the answer and the sample model. Anyway, in the real case scenario the Product table should be read directly from the data source.

Comment: Okay, I guess my database is more complex then I realised at first and I probably should have done this right away: is there a way to give you an extraction of more accurate/realistic data and tables from the database? I've put them in a pbix-file. Can I get that to you in any way to work from?  
I hope you are willing to help me further.

Comment: Of course, you can share your pbix by putting a link in a comment or your original question, using google drive or dropbox or onedrive or any file sharing service you use :)

Comment: of course, take care to remove/anonymize any sensitive data first

Comment: Thanks for this in advance! Here's the link to google drive. https://drive.google.com/file/d/13f5KnZdHqbi0z0JDwuhxG9VQFzbGv0Lt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks. I'll give you some specifics as to where an extra difficulty appears: for example take a look at ordernumber LIN-320102013. There's a qty_order of 2 for artnr ...._X2. This product has a qty_pick of 2 also. That means the orderpicker needs to pick 2 x 2 = 4 times the EAN for this product. In Stock there's to see that this EAN needs to be picked still (items waiting to arrive) 2 times. Another extra input is the artnr is only unique in the Product-table. In all other tables it's not unique. EAN isn't always unique to only an artnr. There's also some examples of this in the data I sent.

Comment: Blank eans complicated the scenario a bit. I shared the solution from github, please check that the number are correct, since I didn't :)
https://github.com/SergioMurru/shared/blob/main/Ekfa%20How%20to%20retrieve%20products%20that%20are%20in%20waiting%20to%20arrive%20mode/Waiting-to-Arrive%20Products.pbix

Comment: After posting the last comment I saw you last comment. So my solution doesn't implement it, yet.

Comment: Your main problem is that you don't have a key for the product. I implemented a quick one for the purpose of the demo. I also had to add products missing from product-color table. For _X2 quantities I added a calculated column. You can find the updated pbix at the previous link to my github :)

Comment: You should consider to move the model creation to ETL or power-query, maybe creating a surrogate key to be used for ProductKey

Comment: I'll check it out further on this week, due to other activities. Thanks for your quick responses.

Comment: I'm working on this again. There are some problems to be solved and i"m trying to figure those out with your demo (which is great you made it). What I run across now is a message saying it "cannot convert [...] text to number" for the measure in order_rows `ean_qty_order = order_rows[qty_order] * RELATED('Product'[qty_pick])`

Comment: this means that one of the columns qty_order of qty_pick is of type text. Check your power queries to ensure that they apply the correct data type. By the way: the ean_qty_order is a calculated column and not a measure. In DAX this makes a great difference: a measure doesn't have a row context and referring directly to a column like for instance "order_rows[qty_order]" would not be possible without a row context.

Comment: Finally I got this to work (after letting a month or so lay in the dark). The problem I mentioned earlier about "cannot convert text to number" was a stupidity of myself. Instead of using 'Product'[gty_pick] I used 'Product'[artnr] which obviously isn't a number...

Comment: THANKS FOR THE GREAT HELP, SERGIOM !

Comment: Would there be any way to get the total amount of products ordered per order? That should be the addition of all 'ean_qty_order' per 'order_id'.

Comment: That would be a different question. You might open a new question, also because at the moment I'm rather busy and probably someone else might answer before I find enough spare time to dive back into this model. :)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I already started typing a new question, but as you might remember: it's quite a difficult datastructure to explain ;-)

Comment: I suggest you to post the sample data as markdown table, this way it may be easily imported in Power BI using the Web data source. This site is very helplful to build markdown tables https://thisdavej.com/copy-table-in-excel-and-paste-as-a-markdown-table/